# Check The Series

Tags: sequences-and-series, algorithms

If the nth term of a series is given by $T(n)=T(n-1) + T(n-1) \times C$ where $C$ is a given constant and $T(1)=A$ and $n \ge 2$ . I need to tell whether its value will be greater than $G$ or not before its mth term.

EXAMPLE :  Say A that is first term is $2$ and say $C$ is also $2$ . If we need to check weather its value is atleast $10(=G)$ before or upto 2nd term.

Then answer should be No.

I need to just check it if its possible or not but without calculating the values. Can anyone help.If all the variables can be very large(say of order $10^9$).

Comment: Are you sure that $T(n)=T(n-1)+C\times T(n-1)$? or $T(n)=T(n-1)+C\times T(n-2)$?

Comment: @mathlove No..i had written it right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since
$$T(n)=(1+C)T(n-1)$$
we have
$$T(n)=(1+C)^{n-1}T(1)=(1+C)^{n-1}A.$$

Hence, you can use the followings (we suppose that $A\gt0$) :

$$T(n)\ge G\iff (1+C)^{n-1}A\ge G\iff(1+C)^{n-1}\ge\frac{G}{A}\iff n\ge\log_{1+C}\frac GA+1,$$
$$T(n)\lt G\iff n\lt \log_{1+C}\frac{G}{A}+1.$$

Here, we suppose that $C\gt -1, C\not=0.$

So, for example, if $A=2, C=2, G=10$, we have
$$T(n)\ge G\iff n\ge\log_{3}\frac{10}{2}+1=\log_{3}5+1,\ \ T(n)\lt G\iff n\lt \log_{3}5+1.$$
Note that $\log_{3}5\approx 1.465.$

Comment: Check ur series.It should be n-1 in power i suppose

Comment: Oh, you are right.

Comment: I think u should correct it.Remaining all seems good...:)

Answer (score 0):

$T(n)=T(n-1)+T(n-1)*C$

$T(n)=(1+C)*T(n-1)$

$T(n)=(1+C)^{n-1}*T(1)$

$T(n)=(1+C)^{n-1}*A$

Do you need something more?

Answer (score 0):

**HINT**

Assuming that the formula you wrote is the right one (see mathlove's comment), you then have
T(n) = (1+C) T(n-1) with T(1) = A.
Then
T(2) = (1+C) T(1),
T(3) = (1+C) T(2) = (1+C)^2 A
....
T(n) = A (1+C)^(n-1)

This looks like a geometric progression, isn't ?

I am sure you can take from here.